# how to get month name from system calender? using mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I am new in mvc.

what I have to code in controller? what I have to change in view? can any one explain me?

I have to display month name and year instead of month1 same for month2

please anyone help me?

view

Month 1
                
                
                    Month 2

```
            </th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black; width:170px;">
                Month 3
            </th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is create a HtmlHelper function. Something like:

```
public static class DateHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetMonthName(int monthNumber)
    {

        var dtfi = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        var monthName = dtfi.GetMonthName(monthNumber).ToString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(monthName);
    }
}
```

}

Then you can call it in your Razor view like so:

```
        </th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black; width:170px;">
            @DateHelper.GetMonthName(3)
        </th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: if I want to print year than?

Comment: Where is the year in your data? it should be returned in the MVC view from whatever API/Database you are calling.